# spring boot @transactional true if succeeded

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I'm using spring 4 with spring boot and i need to use @transactional.
Correct me if I'm wrong - @transactional make my function run in 1 transaction with the db so if something went wrong the the function will do rollback and nothing will change in the db, else it will do commit.

I need to update 4 rows (from 4 different tables) at the same time, if one of them fails to update I need to rollback.
So in my service I have this function:

```
@Transactional
public void updateDB(entity1, entity2, entity3, entity 4) {
    save(entity1);
    save(entity2);
    save(entity3);
    save(entity4);
}
```

Now I want that my function will return true if the transaction ended with commit, else I want it to return false.
Is there any way in doing so?

Comment: Make the save functions return true and use that. If you are using spring data `save()` then they already should.

Answer (score 1):

Just for clarity :

> In its default configuration, the Spring Framework’s transaction
>   infrastructure code marks a transaction for rollback only in the case
>   of runtime, unchecked exceptions. That is, when the thrown exception
>   is an instance or subclass of RuntimeException. ( Error instances
>   also, by default, result in a rollback). Checked exceptions that are
>   thrown from a transactional method do not result in rollback in the
>   default configuration.

Note that you can rollback for Business Exception by using the `rollbackFor` property of the `@Transactional`, for example :

```
@Transactionl(rollBackFor=MyBusinessException.class)
public boolean myTransactionalMethod(){
 // stuff here
}
```

For what you want just return true at the end of your method updateDB :

```
@Transactional
public boolean updateDB(entity1, entity2, entity3, entity 4) {
    save(entity1);
    save(entity2);
    save(entity3);
    save(entity4);
    return true;
}
```

if it doesn't return true that means that your transaction is rolled back

**PS** : Another note from [spring documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/data-access.html#transaction-declarative-annotations)

> In proxy mode (which is the default), only external method calls
>   coming in through the proxy are intercepted. This means that
>   self-invocation (in effect, a method within the target object calling
>   another method of the target object) does not lead to an actual
>   transaction at runtime even if the invoked method is marked with
>   @Transactional. Also, the proxy must be fully initialized to provide
>   the expected behavior, so you should not rely on this feature in your
>   initialization code (that is, @PostConstruct).

Comment: but that doesn't return false in case of an exception

Comment: @Janar you've right I don't return `false` **explicitly** ! , we can test on `updateDB == true` or `updateDB != true`

Answer (score 0):

you can implement it in many way a very simple way may be return true at the end in fact only if your method end with the return instruction you can get the result and the transaction manager will garantee you that the transaction is finished and all the save are on the same transaction.

However pleas! pay attention if save(entity) method is of the same class of updateDB(....) the save will be not in transaction even if your class or methods are marked with @Transaction. This is a tricky "feature" of Spring that is correlated to the spring auto proxy. The magical Transaction is fired and propagated because your class is wrapped around to a Proxy that delegate Spring to manage the transaction for you. This is true for teh Spring bean that on the bean creation lifecycle are proxed with the necessary component. However if in your @Transactional class A you call an other method of class A the your service call do not pass from proxy and the second service call is not in transaction.

I give you an example:

```
@Transactional
class A {


    public Entity save(Entity e) {
        .....
    }

    public Entity update(Entity e) {
        .....
        // the save method is not proxed becouse it is callled from the current instance and not
        // form the proxed spring bean instance
        save(e);
        ...
    }
}



@Transactional
class SaveA {


    public Entity save(Entity e) {
.....
    }


}

@Transactional
class UpdateA {


    private final SaveA saveA;

    UpdateA(SaveA saveA) {
        this.saveA = saveA;
    }

    public Entity update(Entity e) {
        .....
        // the save method is proxed becouse it is called from saveA that is a proxed bean
        saveA.save(e);
        ...
    }

}
```

Comment: He can also annotate the save method with Transactional without having the need put the save method on another class annotated with @Transactional !

Comment: no unfortunately is no true, I say this for my personal experience!!!!!!

Comment: I remember very well debbugging the spring code that in this case the TransactionalAdvice is not triggered.

Comment: ok probably I had explane bad the my think I try to elaborate well and reply soon

Comment: the your last update confirm what I think..... it is clear that I had explain bad the my thinking

Comment: I don't think so, your question is right and clear ;) !

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/187289/discussion-between-valerio-vaudi-and-abdelghani-roussi).

Comment: the function updateDB is in the same class as of save(entity1), but none of my save(entity) functions are annotated with @Transactional, it should work, right?

Comment: no have @Transactional is needed on class or on any methods that should be part of a transaction otherwise spring do not know how participate on transaction, propagation policy isolation and so on. But if two methods are on the same class the inner methods not pass from the proxy and all the inner methods do not will participate in the transaction like said in the answer

Answer (score 0):

It is difficult to do this. The actual commit happens after the method under @Transactional returns. For example, some of the checks that the database needs to do are done when the data is written to the table. For example, a constraint violation on the database will only be caught when the data gets written to the disk. By the time that happens, the method has already returned. So even if you return the status from the method, you will have situations when your method returns success while the database has performed a rollback due to some error.